# Ionic window.open not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I know this is a duplicate question but none of the solutions seem to work for me. This works perfectly fine on Android and in browser but on iOS nothing happens.

html:

`<img ng-src="{{coupon.mainImage}}" ng-click="openWindow(coupon.site)">`

openWindow function:

`$scope.openWindow = function(site) {
     window.open(site, '_system');
 }`

I've also tried using the InAppBrowser plugin but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which behavior do you exactly want on iOS ?

Comment: @Aynolor Sorry, I would like it to open the URL in `coupon.site` in a separate system browser window.

Comment: Ok so you actually need InAppBrowser plugin. What's going on when you call `$cordovaInAppBrowser.open` with `_system` target ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the InAppBrowser cordova plugin like someone stated. You could then create a util method like this:

```
  sendToUrl(url: string): void {
        if (window.cordova) {
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system');
        } else {
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }
    }
```